# dynamic sql statement insertion issue

Tags: sql-server

I have created a Temp table(#TempTable). I am trying to insert the date to get but I am getting an error. It's a dynamic query.

I am trying to get the date from another table and inserting the date to temp table

Just to make sure you understand the problem I have given an example

```
DECLARE @OfferEndDateTime datetime
SELECT @OfferEndDateTime = getdate()-1
print @VOfferEndDateTime


DECLARE @SQL VarChar(1000)
SELECT @SQL ='INSERT INTO #TempTable '+
'SELECT D,Points,@OfferEndDateTime '
exec(@sql)
```

Please  Let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: may be @OfferEndDateTime  should be outside single quote.means u have to concat it to ur query string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use sp_executesql when passing a parameter to dynamic sql

```
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@OfferEndDateTime datetime', @OfferEndDateTime=@OfferEndDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You have, at least, three problems:

1. The variable needs to be outside:

> ```
> SELECT @SQL ='INSERT INTO #TempTable '+
> 'SELECT D,Points,' + @OfferEndDateTime
> ```

1. The variable needs to be varchar type or similar
2. What is `D,Points`? They are not defined anywhere. If they are varchar values you nead to quote them (use " or '') for that purpose.

---

If you need to use the `parameter like datetime` you should use `sp_executesql` instead. Check [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for some info on it!